# How to put the text "Incl VAT" before incl price?

Tags: magento2, tax, localisation

Where do I put the text "Incl VAT" before price? I found 'Excl VAT' but I can't find 'Incl VAT'.

I know how to display both in and excl but not how I put the text "incl vat" before the price.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w8yok1f3mv5gxot/Schermafdruk%202018-08-06%2010.13.58.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

You can configure it from magento admin itself. See the below configuration:

> Stores->Configuration->Sales->Tax->Price Display Settings

Comment: This answer is not useful. Look at the link. I know how to display both in and excl but not how i put the text "incl vat" before the price.

Answer (score 1):

After you've enabled the viewing of taxes from the admin section, you can check to see how the "Excl VAT" is being displayed in the HTML. You'll notice it's via CSS (Magento 2.3)

```
.price-including-tax + .price-excluding-tax::before, .weee[data-label]::before{
        content: attr(data-label) ': ';
    }
```

Therefore simply add the following to your _extend.less file to enable the "Inc VAT" to show up, you may wish to adjust the font size as well:

```
.price-including-tax::before{
        content: attr(data-label) ': ';
    }
```